# How we add data to grid view on successful

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I created a grid view which show a list. Now i have an issue when user successful post a data i want to add this in data in grid view, but not want to load whole grid view, Just want to add data in previous grid. Can body tell me if this possible how i achieve this?

> [image]

Here is the code for my adapter:-

```
        package com.idea.remote;

        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import java.util.List;


        import com.idea.*;
        import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class UserPostsListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserPostsItemForm> {

           Context context;
           List<UserPostsItemForm> items;
           public UserPostsListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                   List<UserPostsItemForm> items) {
               super(context, resourceId, items);
               this.context = context;
               this.items=items;
           }

           /*private view holder class*/
           private class ViewHolder {
               ImageView imageView;
               TextView txtUserName;
               TextView txtDesc;
               TextView sweetNo;
               TextView idealCount;
               TextView userId;
               TextView postID;
               ImageView replyId;
               ImageView addFriend;
               ImageView sweetButton;
               ImageView imageView4;
               ImageView imageView2;
           }

           @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               ViewHolder holder = null;
                UserPostsItemForm rowItem = getItem(position);

               LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                       .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               if (convertView == null) {
                   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_posts, null);
                   holder = new ViewHolder();
                   holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                   holder.txtUserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
                   holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                   holder.sweetNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sweetNo);
                   holder.idealCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idealCount);
                   holder.sweetButton= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sweetButton);
                   holder.imageView4= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                   holder.imageView2= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

                   final String userId1=items.get(position).getUserId();

            ImageView addFriend1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.addFriend=addFriend1;
            holder.addFriend.setTag(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getUserId()));
            holder.addFriend.setTag(userId1); //For passing the list item index
            final String addFriendTag=(String) holder.addFriend.getTag();
            holder.addFriend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, " is "+ addFriendTag,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }     
        });

          convertView.setTag(holder);
               } else
                   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

               //for sweet button like
               holder.sweetButton.setTag(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getPostID()));
               final int sweetButtonTag= (Integer) holder.sweetButton.getTag();
               holder.sweetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "sweetbutton is "+ sweetButtonTag,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    String userId="18";
                        voteUpDownWallPost wallPost2=new voteUpDownWallPost(sweetButtonTag,userId,context,"AddWallPostVoteUp");
                        wallPost2.sendTopost();
                }     
             });

               //for ideal button like
               holder.imageView4.setTag(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getPostID()));
               final int idealButtonTag= (Integer) holder.imageView4.getTag();
               holder.imageView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "ideal button is "+ idealButtonTag,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    String userId="18";
                        voteUpDownWallPost wallPost2=new voteUpDownWallPost(idealButtonTag,userId,context,"AddWallPostVoteDown");
                        String status=wallPost2.sendTopost();
                        if(status=="true"){
                           //   holder.sweetNo.setText(rowItem.getSweetNo()+1);

                        }
                }     
             });


               //reply button 
                holder.imageView2.setTag(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getUserId()));
               final int replyButtonTag= (Integer) holder.imageView2.getTag();
               holder.imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "reply  is "+ replyButtonTag,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    String userId="18";
                        //voteUpDownWallPost wallPost2=new voteUpDownWallPost(replyButtonTag,userId,context,"AddWallPostVoteDown");
                    //  String status=wallPost2.sendTopost();
                    /// if(status=="true"){
                           //   holder.sweetNo.setText(rowItem.getSweetNo()+1);

                    //  }
                }     
             });



               holder.sweetButton.setTag(rowItem.getPostID());
               holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
               holder.txtUserName.setText(rowItem.getUserName());
               holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(rowItem.getImageId());
               holder.sweetNo.setText(rowItem.getSweetNo());
               holder.idealCount.setText(rowItem.getIdealCount());
               return convertView;
           }


        }
```

and one more thing. How i change previously added text for like and sweet button count.

And this is my onclick post button which is in activity class:-

```
postButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText data=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
                    String wallPost=data.getText().toString();
                    String userId="18";
                    SendUserWallPost wallPost2=new SendUserWallPost(wallPost,userId,context);
                    String status= wallPost2.sendTopost();
                    // ad.setMessage(status);
                   //  ad.show(); 
                    Intent callMenuClass = new Intent(BlackboardLayout.this, BlackboardLayout.class);  
                    startActivity(callMenuClass); 
                    //fillListPost();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add new post like this:

```
 Post post = new Post();
 UserPostsListViewAdapter.add(post);
 UserPostsListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Where i insert this code? in activity class or in list view adapter?

Comment: And what is post class here?

Comment: Sorry, the post is your `UserPostsItemForm` class,and you could add the code when you do a operation like add a UserPostsItemForm.

Comment: Ya but when i inserting your code its saying can't cant make a static reference to the  non-static method.

Comment: Can you post the code for me(in Github or somewhere else)?

Comment: First,you should define the `UserPostsListViewAdapter` as a global variable,such as `UserPostsListViewAdapter userPostsListViewAdapter`,then you initial `userPostsListViewAdapter` when you want to add the initial data to the `userPostsListViewAdapter`. All the code is to fill initial data for listview.Then if you want to add data when you click the button,you should use `userPostsListViewAdapter.add(post)` and `userPostsListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thank you its working but its showing data to the bottom means on last, I want it on top. And also want to scroll down.

Comment: Just use `userPostsListViewAdapter.insert(post,0)`;

Comment: Wow you are awesome. Now its working. But what i do for like button because this button is in adapter and i am creating this dynamically.

Comment: set the button's onclicklistener in the adapter.

Comment: Ya, I all-ready created but how i update the content of adapter?